# I am trying to create a django query that returns the posts that are of post_type "mobiles"

Tags: django, django-queryset, web-deployment

```
class Entry(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     post_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="others")
     author = models.CharField(max_length=30, default = "")
     body = models.TextField()
     slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 200, unique = True)
     publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

     objects = EntryQuerySet.as_manager()

     def __str__(self):
        return self.title

     class Meta:
         verbose_name = "Blog Entry"
         verbose_name_plural = "Blog Entries"
         ordering = ["-created"]
```

The above code is my models.py

```
class MobilesIndex(generic.ListView):
    queryset = models.Entry.objects.get(post_type="Mobile")
    template_name = "index.html"
    paginate_by = 5

def Mobiles(request):
    context = locals()
    template = "Mobiles.html"
    return render(request,template,context)
```

The above code is view.py

how do i write the query that has only the posts that are of post_type="Mobile"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
queryset = models.Entry.objects.filter(post_type="Mobile")
```

this will give you all the post type and to render in template you need to loop it

Comment: I tried to loop it.. It is supposed to to show posts of type "mobiles" ,But after I added                                                                                      queryset = models.Entry.objects.filter(post_type="Mobile")                              It keeps redirecting to the index.html page

Comment: I tried to loop it.. It is supposed to to show posts of type "mobiles" in the Mobiles page ,But after I added                                                                                      queryset = models.Entry.objects.filter(post_type="Mobile")                              It keeps redirecting to the index.html page                                  [22/Jun/2017 12:18:17] "GET /Mobiles/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7437
[22/Jun/2017 12:18:18] "GET /Mobiles/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7437
I even get the GET reponse from server.. but stillit goes to index.html

Comment: but your template name is index. if you want to show in mobiles page then put the queryset in the Mobiles function

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
Entry.objects.fitler(post_type="Mobile")
```

[**get()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get) return ONE object or exeception if not exists/multiple objects, but [**filter()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) returns all objects (or None if no objects).